# Data encryption in exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

How encrypted data of salesforce is transferred to exact target.
Currently we are using third party system to encrypt data in salesforce and we need to automatically integrate salesforce and ET.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The question is very old so you might already have the answer. But here's my understanding.

Marketing Cloud Connect supports Classic encryption done on fields in Sales or Service Cloud and shows data to the users based on View Encrypted Data permission. If you want to use Salesforce's standard encryption features, check the link [Marketing Cloud Connect Encryption](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/key_concepts/marketing_cloud_connect_encryption) for more details.

I don't think this will work for custom third party encryption unless Salesforce can make a backend update to support your custom encryption algorithm. It's a long shot, but do check with Salesforce to confirm.